# $f(n)=\sqrt{m+f(n-1)}, f(1)=\sqrt{m}.$ Find the general term of $f(n).$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations

> $f(n)=\sqrt{m+f(n-1)}, f(1)=\sqrt{m}.$ Find the general term of $f(n).$

Linked question: [How can we prove $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+....\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)$ without induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4498537/979028)

I just answered the question above, and another question popped into my head. I was curious about the general term of $\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\cdots\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m}}}}$, instead of $2$. So, I tried some:

\begin{align}
&\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)^2=m+\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n). \\
\therefore \; & \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)=\dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{4m+1}}{2}. \\
& f(n)>0. \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{4m+1}}{2}. \\
\ \\
&f(n) \text{ increases.} \\
\therefore \; & \sqrt{m} \leq f(i) \leq \dfrac{1+\sqrt{4m+1}}{2} \text{ for } \forall i.
\end{align}

How can we proceed?